# How to draw an ellipse arc in 3D?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

There is no Circle or Disk object in 3D. I quickly found a way to use Cylinder (thin lines, no faces, very flat):

```
Module[{s},
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thickness[Small]], FaceForm[None], 
  Cylinder[{s = {1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, s + {0, 1/1000, -2/1000}}, 1/2]}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

But

- orientation of the cylinder is tricky,
- choice of coordinate shift is dependent on graphics size and magnification. I have to take into account the parameters of relative thickness,
- it requires me to make a few auxiliary functions (without speaking for instance if I want to define a circle by center, radius and angles to the axis, or by three points)
- I cannot only draw an arc between 2 angle positions nor make it elliptical.

If I want all this, am I forced to recreate the wheel and construct computationally a 3D polygon approximating an ellipse ?

Comment: I'm surprised `Cylinder[]` does not degenerate gracefully if the endpoints given to it are identical. For a circle arc in 3D, I don't think there's a built-in function for that. Note that you can use `ScalingTransform[]` on your circles to yield ellipses when needed.

Comment: What would your preferred input for your arc be? There are many ways to parametrize...

Comment: @Yves Klett : thanks for your concern and your interesting answer. In fact I asked the question mainly to know if it had been done before, if there was a standard package with this kind of things (an ellipse primitive in 3D). I am able to create the various required parametrizations myself in Mathematica.

Comment: Highly relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to go about drawing a circular arc defined by three points (adjust for ellipses):

```
{a, b, m} = {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}};

{a, b, m} = {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}};

    Arc3D[{a_, b_, m_}, n_: 60, prim_: Line] := 
      Module[{\[Alpha], lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha},
        lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
        axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
        aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
        tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
        prim@Table[m + tm.(a - m), {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}]
        ]

    Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Line[{m, a}], Line[{m, b}], 
        Point[{a, b, m}], Arc3D[{a, b, m}, 20]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This only draws arcs up to $\pi$. I´ll try to elaborate once your specs become a bit clearer (esp. what your preferred input would look like).

Comment: As a note: three points determine a circle, but one needs five points to determine an ellipse.

Comment: @J.M. thusly "circular arc"... never needed a 3D ellipse before ;-)

Comment: Sure. :) It's more of a general reminder for everybody than anything.

Comment: @J.M. : another reminder is that the five points must be coplanar :-)

Comment: @Yves Klett : as it is already, your code will be quite useful to me.

Answer (score 15):

Here is something I have used before to make plots of polarization states in vector fields. It does geometric transformations on a basic shape similar to what `Cylinder` produces:

```
pacman[{θ1_, θ2_}, scale_, thickness_, capStyle_, 
  wedgeStyle_] := {{capStyle, 
   RevolutionPlot3D[
     thickness, {t, 0, scale}, {θ, θ1, θ2}, 
     Mesh -> False][[1]],
   RevolutionPlot3D[-thickness, {t, 0, 
      scale}, {θ, θ1, θ2}, Mesh -> False][[1]]},
  RevolutionPlot3D[{scale, t}, {t, -thickness, 
     thickness}, {θ, θ1, θ2}, Mesh -> False][[1]],
  {wedgeStyle, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, -thickness}, {scale Cos[θ1], 
      scale Sin[θ1], -thickness}, {scale Cos[θ1], 
      scale Sin[θ1], thickness}, {0, 0, 
      thickness}, {scale Cos[θ2], scale Sin[θ2], 
      thickness}, {scale Cos[θ2], 
      scale Sin[θ2], -thickness}}]}}

ellipse3D[abrList_, wedgeList_: {{0, 2 π}}, scale_: .1, 
  thickness_: .01, capStyle_: {}, wedgeStyle_: {}] :=
 {EdgeForm[],
  MapThread[GeometricTransformation[{
      pacman[#2, scale, thickness, capStyle, wedgeStyle]
      },
     AffineTransform[{
       Transpose[
        Append[Most[#], Normalize[Cross @@ Most[#]]]], Last[#]}
      ]] &,
   {abrList, PadRight[wedgeList, Length[abrList], {Last[wedgeList]}]}]}
```

**Edit**

In the above code, I added the ability to draw a filled "arc" of an ellipse, more commonly known as a squished Pacman. The examples below stay the same if you don't specify a pair of angles for the wedge in the ellipse. I'll add an example with a wedge opening below.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red,
  ellipse3D[{
    {
     (* Axes a, b, position r: *)
     {1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, 0}
     }
    }
   ]
  }]
```

[image: ellipse3d]

The function `ellipse3D` takes a **list** of points as its argument, so that I can plot more than a single ellipse at a time. Each element of the list consists of a **three** entries:

```
{a, b, r}
```

where `a` and `b` are three-dimensional vectors pointing in the direction of the semi-major and semi-minor axes. Their length determines the eccentricity of the ellipse. If `a` and `b` aren't perpendicular to each other, you can also produce a skewed ellipse. The third vector `r` is the position at which the ellipse is centered.

The optional arguments `scale` and `thickness` determine the overall size of the object. The lengths given by `a` and `b` are multiplied by `scale` before plotting, and the `z` height of the cylinder which represents the ellipse in 3D is given by `thickness`.

Here is another example that shows how to apply it with a list of ellipses:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Magenta,
  ellipse3D[{
    {
     (* First ellipse; axes a, b, 
     position r: *)
     {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0,
       0}
     },
    {
     (* Second ellipse; axes a, b, 
     position r: *)
     {.5, 1, .5}, {.25, .25, .5}, {1, 1, 1}
     },
    {
     (* Third ellipse; axes a, b, 
     position r: *)
     {-.5, .1, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 1, 
      0.5}
     },
    {
     (* Circle: *)
     {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {.5, 1, 0}
     }
    }]
  }, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

[image: more ellipses]

Here is an ellipse with a wedge:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red,
  ellipse3D[{
    {
     (* Axes a, b, position r: *)
     {1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, 0}
     }
    }
   , {{0, 5}}
   ]
  }]
```

[image: wedge]

The second argument (`wedgeList`) of `ellipse3D` now was specified as a list of angle pairs - one for each ellipse to be drawn. If there is only a single element, all subsequent ellipses specified by the first argument (`abrList`) are drawn with the same angle spans.

**Edit 2**

In order to also be able to draw **open ellipse arcs** I added two further arguments to the function, specifying the **style** in which the different faces of the ellipse are rendered. For the top and bottom faces, the style is in the variable `capStyle` (with the default value `capStyle = {}` cap style is taken from the enclosing graphics). The sides of the wedge can be styled with the last argument, `wedgeStyle`. To *suppress* any of these, use `FaceForm[]`.

For example, here is a hollow pacman:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Red,
  ellipse3D[{
    {
     (* Axes a, b, position r: *)
     {1, 0, 0}, {0, .5, 0}, {0, 0, 0}
     }
    }
   , {{0, 5}}, .1, .01, FaceForm[], Directive[Opacity[.5], Blue]
   ]
  }]
```

[image: hollowpacman]

As an application example, I'll just show a more complicated plot made with this kind of function. It requires too many additional definitions to put into this answer, but you can get a better impression of how 3D ellipses can be really useful:

[image: sphericalHarmonic]

Answer (score 12):

What about using the graphics primitive that can be extracted from `ParametricPlot`?

```
arc = ParametricPlot[{2 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
    Axes -> None][[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
```

We then add a constant value for the third dimension:

```
zeros = Table[0, {Length[arc]}];
arc3D = Partition[Flatten[Transpose[{arc, zeros}]], 3];
```

We can then use this as a 3D graphics primitive:

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[
  Line[arc3D], {RotationMatrix[45 Degree, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 1}}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, SphericalRegion -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image: arc]

Comment: Nice reuse of existing Mathematica functions that can be applied to many other things. But indeed, the simplest would perhaps be to use ParametricPlot3D directly?

Answer (score 6):

You may try

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}/1000}, 2]}]
```

for a circle. With a color instead of `FaceForm` you get a disk

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}/1000}, 2]}]
```

Another way is to use e.g. `ParametricPlot3D` and applying some transformations as J.M. suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 5):

Composed this using parametric equation of a plane:

```
Ellipse3D[a_, b_, P0_, n1_, n2_, Op_] := Module[{},
     ParametricPlot3D[P0 +
     (a Cos[phi]) Normalize[n1] + 
     (b Sin[phi]) Normalize[n2], 
     {phi, -Pi, Pi}, Op]
```

Here's how:

```
X = x0 + t1 S1 + t2 S2 , where

    X -> {X1, X2, X3} is translated point from (X1, X2) plane to (X1, X2, X3) space,
    x0 -> {x1, x2, x3} is translation offset from coordinate origin 
        (desired ellipse center-point P0),
    S1 -> {U1, U2, U3} and S2 -> {V1, V2, V3} 
        are base vectors of the translated coordinate system, thus they become
        normalized vectors of the desired directions of ellipse's 
        semi-major and -minor axis respectively,
    t1 and t2 are plane parameters.
    From ellipse's parametric form they become t1 = a Cos[phi] and t2 = b Sin[phi],
    a and b being the semi-major and -minor axis lengths.
```

Op is vector for plotting options.

Here's an example:

```
Show[Ellipse3D[3,2,P0,R1,R2,PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thin}],
Ellipse3D[3,2,P0,{1,0,0},{0,1,0},PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}],
Graphics3D[Arrow[{P0,P0+R1}]],
Graphics3D[Arrow[{P0,P0+R2}]],AxesLabel -> {"X","Y","Z"}, PlotRange -> Automatic ]
```

[image: ]]

The dashed blue line represents the untranslated ellipse on X-Y plane and the continous "blue" ellipse is the one translated to XYZ space.

Plotting parameters:

```
P0 = {1,1,1};
R1 = {-Sqrt[2]/2, 1, 0};
R2 = {1, Sqrt[2]/2, 1};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new "SplineCircle" [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) to do this. Example:

```
Graphics3D[
    {
    Thick,
    ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0, 0, 0}, {1,3}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {0, 3Pi/2}]
    },
    Boxed->False,
    AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
    Axes->True,
    AxesEdge->{.5,.5,.5},
    AxesLabel->{x, y, z}
]
```

[image]

The syntax is `ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][center, {r1, r2}, {u, v}, angle]` where `r1` and `r2` are the two axis lengths, and `{u, v}` defines the plane of the ellipse, with `r1` in the direction `u`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to plot 3D ellipse would be

```
Scale[Cylinder[{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, 0.1}}, 1], {wx, wy, 1}]
```

where x, y gives the location and wx, wy give the length of major and minor axis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's useful to anyone. As a mathematica newby, I was looking for a 'more intuitive' method of plotting 2D ellipses in 3D space. Here's my solution, for an ellipse with (axis of length a along unit vector ehatA) and (axis of length b along unit vector ehatB):

```
ellipsePoints[t_, position_, aEllipse_, bEllipse_, ehatA_, ehatB_] := position + aEllipse Cos[t] ehatA + bEllipse Sin[t] ehatB;

ellipse1[t_] := 
    kitePoints[t, positionTest, aEllipseTest, bEllipseTest, ehatATest, ehatBTest]

listEllipsePoints = Range[0, 2 Pi 100 ]/100;

ellipseGraph = Graphics3D[{Black, 
    Polygon[Map[ellipse1, listEllipsePoints]]
    }, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}];
```