# How to draw a coordinate system diagram?

Tags: graphics3d

I want to make drawings like these in *Mathematica*:

[image: sc]
[image]

I don't know if *Mathematica* is a gppd solution for drawing such images.  If it is, please tell me how to do it; if not, please suggest another solution.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Does that answer your question? If not and you want help actually drawing that trying showing what you have tried so far and where you are having trouble.

Comment: @s0rce - I'm making a document with equations and want to draw the two coordinate systems, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the title to something like "how to draw a coordinate system in mathematica", so search engines can index it.

Comment: @Zet - Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be late but I post for illustration:

```
orig = {0, 0, 0};
axes = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
pt = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
arc1 = Table[
   RotationMatrix[j, {0, 0, 1}].{0.5, 0, 0}, {j, 0, Pi/4, 0.01}];
ang = VectorAngle[{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}];
axis = Cross[{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}];
arc2 = Table[RotationMatrix[j, axis].{0, 0, 0.5}, {j, 0, ang, 0.01}];
labels = {
  Text[Style["\[Theta]", 12], RotationMatrix[ang/2, axis].{0, 0, 0.6}],
  Text[Style["\[Phi]", 12], 
   RotationMatrix[Pi/8, {0, 0, 1}].{0.6, 0, 0}],
  Text[Style[TraditionalForm["r"], 12], (orig + pt)/2 + {0, 0, -0.05}],
  Text[Style["P", Italic, 12], 1.1 pt],
  Text[Column[{"(x,y,z)", "(r,\[Theta],\[Phi])"}], 
   1.2 pt - {0, 0, 0.1}],
  MapThread[
   Text[#1, #2] &, {Style[#, 12] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, 1.1 axes}]
  }
```

Assembling into graphic object:

```
Graphics3D[{Arrow[{orig, #}] & /@ axes, {Red, Arrow[{orig, pt}]}, 
  Line[{orig, {0.5, 0.5, 0}}], Line[{{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}],
   Line[arc1], 
  Line[arc2], {Opacity[0.2], 
   Polygon[{orig, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, {Opacity[0.2], 
   Polygon[{orig, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, labels}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

Does not have all elements (left brace, shading of planes, z on vertical drop)  but illustrative.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bit of manual, but can be a staring point, Arc3D function from [How to draw an ellipse arc in 3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-arc-in-3d):

```
Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
 {Dashed, Line[{{.6, 0, 0}, {.6, .6, 0}}]}, 
 Arc3D[{{.3, 0, 0}, {.3, .3, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 30],
 Line[{{.6, .6, 0}, {.6, .6, .6}}],
 {PointSize[Medium], Point[{.6, .6, .6}]},
 Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {.6, .6, 0}}],
 Text[Style["O", Italic, Bold, 13], {0, 0, 0}, {2, -1}],
 Text[Style["x", Italic, Bold, 12], {1, 0, 0}, {-3, 0}],
 Text[Style["y", Italic, Bold, 12], {0, 1, 0}, {-2, 0}],
 Text[Style["z", Italic, Bold, 12], {0, 0, 1}, {-3, 1}]},
 Boxed -> False, PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

Comment: +1, but you're missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: @halmir - Thank you!

Comment: @Anon thanks, I fixed it.