# How to draw a Circle in 3D on a sphere

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

The `Circle` function is strictly a 2D `Graphics` object, so that we cannot directly combine a `Circle` with a `Graphics3D` object such as a sphere:

```
 Show[{ Graphics3D[Sphere[] , Circle[]] }]
```

> (* Circle is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive *)

How can I draw circle in 3D?

For example consider a unit `Sphere[]` centered at the origin. How can we draw a circle passing through a specified point with the circle center along a vector passing through a second point.

Comment: Did you try something ? Like reading in the documentation about *Graphics* ?

Comment: @Kuba I know, I know, searching is so tedious, but .. :D

Comment: @kuba @sektor Now now. Using the undocumented function `Read@Mind[{}]` is not for everyone. Isn't there a badge for achieving the [Beginner's Mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshin)?

Comment: @m_goldberg but this one is not about great circle.

Comment: If the center of the circle lies on the sphere it is impossible that the circle itself lies on the sphere.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it depends what do you mean by circle.

Comment: @kuba please elaborate.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Circle is a 1-Sphere in Euclidean space. If you consider 1-Sp in space which is 2-Sphere (just a sphere) it fits the description. But I don't know what conventions are used so I do not insist. Your comment is of course on topic.

Comment: I hope its ok, I took the liberty of improving the question because there are a number of good answers here..and the question appears in danger of being closed.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6526/, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10957/

Comment: @MichaelE2 very close but the input is really sphere center, and two points on sphere where one is not a center of created circle. (in euclidean meaning). but maybe close enough to close it :)

Comment: Related Wolfram Community thread: "[Graphing 2D circles in 3D](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/508106?p_p_auth=BlsSgD6Q)."

Answer (score 64):

## Circle

Let's create `circle3D` that is something you would expect from `Circle` but with an extra argument for its normal vector.

With

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=
  Composition[
    Line,
    Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &,
    Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &,
    Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &,
    Level[#, {-2}] &,
    MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &,
    DiscretizeRegion,
    If
  ][
    First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi,
    Circle[Most@centre, radius],
    Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]
  ]
```

we can produce, for example, the following.

A unit circle centred at the origin with the z-axis as its normal:

```
Graphics3D[circle3D[]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

A unit circle centred at `{2, 3, 4}` with the z-axis as its normal:

```
Graphics3D[circle3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

A circle centred at `{2, 3, 4}` with radius `2` and the z-axis as its normal:

```
Graphics3D[circle3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

A circle centred at `{2, 3, 4}` with radius `2` and normal vector pointing in the direction of $\hat\imath - \hat\jmath + \hat{k}$:

```
Graphics3D[circle3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2, {1, -1, 1}]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

An arc, drawn from 0 to 180 degrees, of a circle whose origin is centred at `{2, 3, 4}`, radius is `2`, and normal vector points in the direction of $\hat\imath - \hat\jmath + \hat{k}$:

```
Graphics3D[circle3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2, {1, -1, 1}, {0, 180 Degree}]]
```

[image: 3D circle]

## Neat Examples

```
tocartesian = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
circles = MapThread[
  circle3D[{0, 0, 0}, #1, tocartesian[{#1, #2, 0}]] &,
  {Range[37], Range[0 Degree, 360 Degree, 10 Degree]}
];
ListAnimate@Table[
  Graphics3D[
    Rotate[#, n Degree, {0, 1, 0}] & /@ circles,
    Boxed -> False,
    PlotRange -> 37 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
  ],
  {n, 180}
]
```

[image: 3D circles]

```
tocartesian = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
spherecentre = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
sphereradius = RandomReal[{1, 2}];
dotsize = sphereradius/20;
randcirc := Module[
  {circleradius, randompoint},
  circleradius = RandomReal[{dotsize, sphereradius}];
  randompoint = TranslationTransform[spherecentre][
    tocartesian[{sphereradius, RandomReal[{0, Pi}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}]
  ];
  {
    RandomColor[],
    Sphere[randompoint, dotsize],
    circle3D[
      spherecentre +
        Sqrt[sphereradius^2 - circleradius^2] Normalize[randompoint - spherecentre],
      circleradius,
      randompoint - spherecentre
    ]
  }
];
Graphics3D[
  {
    {Opacity[0.3, LightGray], Sphere[spherecentre, sphereradius]},
    Thick,
    Table[randcirc, {10}]
  },
  Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: 3D circles]

## Extras

### Disk

Likewise, we can construct `disk3D` that behaves like `Disk` but with an extra argument for its normal vector.

```
disk3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=
  Polygon[
    Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre]][
      If[First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, #, Append[#, centre]] &[
        Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &][
          SortBy[#, sortf[#, Most@centre] &] &[
            MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[
              Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]
]]]]]]]
sortf := Composition[
    If[Negative[#], # + 2 Pi, #] &,
    N[ArcTan @@ (#1 - #2)] &
]
```

The sorting of points is adapted from [nikie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/nikie)'s answer in [#48091](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48091)

Examples:

```
Graphics3D[disk3D[]]
```

[image: 3D disk]

```
Graphics3D[disk3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2, {1, -1, 1}, {30 Degree, 180 Degree}]]
```

[image: 3D disk]

It's a `Polygon` after all, so it behaves just like any other region object in Mathematica. You can execute, for example,

```
RegionMeasure[disk3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2, {1, -1, 1}, {30 Degree, 180 Degree}]]
```

and get the area:

> 5.2232

or style it like

```
disk = disk3D[{2, 3, 4}, 2, {1, -1, 1}, {30 Degree, 180 Degree}];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Red, disk}]
```

[image: red 3D disk]

### Ellipse

After `circle3D`, why not `ellipse3D` as well?

```
ellipse3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radii_: {1, 1}, normal_: {0, 0, 1}] := 
  Polygon[
    RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre][
      Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &][
        SortBy[#, N[ArcTan @@ (# - Most@centre)] &] &[
          MeshCoordinates[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
            Ellipsoid[Most@centre, radii]
]]]]]]
```

`Graphics3D[ellipse3D[]]` is equivalent to `Graphics3D[circle3D[]]`:

[image: 3D ellipse]

```
Graphics3D[ellipse3D[{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, -1, 1}]]
```

[image: 3D ellipse]

```
RegionMeasure[ellipse3D[{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, -1, 1}]]
```

> 6.25978

which is a little bit off from that of the same ellipse in 2D:

```
RegionMeasure[Ellipsoid[{2, 3}, {1, 2}]]
```

> 2π

due to the discretisation.

Comment: `Graphics3D[disk3D[{2,3,4},2,{1,-1,1},{90 Degree,270 Degree}]]`has problem.

Comment: @kittygirl Hmmmm I've got to change the `SortBy` Line somehow...

Comment: @kittygirl `disk3D` updated and tested.

Comment: Brilliant example!! Very useful for me. Thanks !!!

Comment: @MsenRezaee You’re welcome!

Comment: `Graphics3D[
 disk3D[{2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, -1, 1}, {90 Degree, 270 Degree}]]`

Answer (score 17):

```
center = Normalize@{1, 2, 3};
point = Normalize@{0, 2, 1};
```

with minimum of algebra:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[ N[center + RotationMatrix[t, center].(point - center)]], 
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Blue, Sphere[{center, point}, .05]}]
 , PlotRange -> 1.1
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm encouraging future readers to keeps scrolling down. Nice answers are awaiting attention :)

Answer (score 10):

circle is 2D and sphere is 3D. Hence you are missing one dimension to make them both show together. i.e. you need orientation for the circle.

This should get you started. You can approximate a circle with Cylinder of very small length.

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Red, Cylinder[{{1, 0, 0}, {1.01, 0, 0}}, 1]},
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: even do: `EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[Transparent]` ..to actually have just a circle.

Comment: Yes, this is very clever. I was thinking of somehow modifying a `Cone[.]` instead, but this is way better.

Answer (score 5):

```
draw[sphere : {sC_, sR_}, circle: {ctr_, pt_}] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[sR {Cos[u] Sin[v],Sin[u] Sin[v],Cos[v]}+sC, {u,0,2 Pi}, {v,0,2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (Norm[{##}[[1;;3]]-ctr] - Norm[ctr-pt] &), Mesh -> {{0}}]

SeedRandom[42];
sCenter = {1, 1, 1}; sRadius = 1;
cs = Map[Plus[Normalize[#], sCenter] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1} sRadius, {10, 2, 3}], {2}]
draw[{sCenter, sRadius}, #] & /@ cs // Show
```

[image]

Also

```
f[r_, u_, v_]= CoordinateTransformData["Spherical"->"Cartesian","Mapping",{r, u, v}]; 

draw1[sphere : {sphC_, sphR_}, ctr_, pt_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[f[sphR, u, v] + sphC, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Norm[{x, y, z} - ctr] - Norm[ctr- pt]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}]

draw1[{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also plot two partial spheres and highlight where they meet

```
 smallSphere = ParametricPlot3D[
   {Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]},
   {θ, -π, π}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.4]},
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],
   RegionFunction -> (#2 > .6 &)
   ];
 bigSphere = ParametricPlot3D[
   {Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]},
   {θ, -π, π}, {ϕ, -π/2, π/2},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]},
   RegionFunction -> (#2 < .6 &)
   ];
Show[bigSphere, smallSphere, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `Exclusions` with `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, -π, π}, {v, -π/2, π/2}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, Blue], PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4,
 Exclusions -> {Cos[u] Cos[v] == .7}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> ({Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've found this useful on a number of occasions: use a `BezierCurve`, which can be a 3D object,  to approximate a circle.

```
 bezierarc[xc_, a_, b_ , r_: 1, n_: {0, 0, 1}] := 
   (* Bezier approximation to an arc *)
   (*Excellent approximation for included angle b-a < Pi/2 *)
   (* "pretty good" approximation for b-a< Pi *)
   Module[{rstar, del, p, c, d},
   c = (a + b)/2;
   d = (a - b)/2;
   rstar = (8 - ( Cos@a + Cos@b )/Cos@c )/6;
   del = (13 Sin@d - 8  Sin[d/2] Sqrt[14 + 2 Cos@d ])/9;
   p = r {
     {Cos[a], Sin[a]} ,
     rstar {Cos[c], Sin[c]} -   del {-Sin[c], Cos[c]} ,
     rstar  {Cos[c], Sin[c]} +   del  {-Sin[c], Cos[c]} ,
     {Cos[b], Sin[b]}};
   If[Length[xc] == 3 , 
      p = RotationMatrix[{ {0, 0, 1}, n}]. Append[#, 0] & /@ p];
   BezierCurve[xc + # & /@ p]]
 beziercircle[xc_, r_: 1, n_: {0, 0, 1}] := 
    bezierarc[xc, Sequence @@ # , r, n ] & /@  (Pi /2 Partition[Range[0, 4], 2, 1])
```

This is designed to work in 2- or 3-d:

```
 GraphicsRow[{Graphics@beziercircle[{0, 0}, 1] ,
    Graphics3D@{beziercircle[{0, 0, 0}, 1, {1, 1, 1}], 
           Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}] }}]
```

[image]

for the example at hand,

```
   center = Normalize@{1, 2, 3};
   point = Normalize@{0, 2, 1};
```

of course the true circle center is not actually on the sphere so we need to do a bit of math:

```
 cc = center First@
     Select[ f /. 
           Solve[ (f center  - point ).(f center) == 0 , f ] , # > 0 & ]
 Graphics3D[{ Sphere[] , Thick, Red, 
      beziercircle[cc, Norm[point - cc], center] , Blue, 
          Sphere[#, .05] & /@ {center, point}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how the beginning and the end are defined. Could you give an example: two points on unit sphere {\theta_1,\phi_1} and  {\theta_2,\phi_2} - what should be used in the last entry (in the basic example it's {0, 180 Degree}).