# Replicate an image from Documentation Center (EulerMatrix)

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

**EDIT**

I try to produce an image similar to that

[image]

(see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerMatrix.html)) but this time with an **ellipsoid**.
I hope I am not wrong but the code that creates this beautiful image is not available in Mathematica's Help Browser (I guess it was created in Mathematica).

Thanks to the replies I got in the recent similar posts, I use the following approach:

First the elliptical cross sections.

```
ellipse3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radii_: {1, 1}, normal_: {0, 0, 1}] := 
 Polygon[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre][
   Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &][
    SortBy[#, N[ArcTan @@ (# - Most@centre)] &] &[
     MeshCoordinates[
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[Most@centre, radii]]]]]]]
(*ellipse to 3D*)
```

Adopted from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99958/how-to-include-2-dimensional-disks-in-a-graphics3d-object-ellipsoid).

Next the non-rotated system of axis with its label.

```
arrowAxes[{a_, b_, c_}, arrowstyle_: {}, n1_: 1.5] := {arrowstyle, 
  Arrowheads[Large], 
  Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] &, {a + n1, b + n1, 
     c + n1} IdentityMatrix[3]]}

labelAxes[{a_, b_, c_}, {o1_String: "X", o2_String: "Y", 
   o3_String: "Z"}, col_: Black, 
  n2_: 2] := {col, {Text[
    Style[o1, 20, Italic], {a + n2 - 0.2, 0, -0.5}], 
   Text[Style[o2, 20, Italic], {0, b + n2, -0.6}], 
   Text[Style[o3, 20, Italic], {0, 0.6, c + n2 - 0.2}]}}
```

The non-rotated ellipsoid (with its cross sections).

```
ellipsoidXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}] := {{Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.3], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}, {{Red, Opacity[0.9], 
    EdgeForm[None], ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {c, b}, {1, 0, 0}]}, {Blue, 
    Opacity[0.9], EdgeForm[None], 
    ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {a, c}, {0, 1, 0}]}, {Orange, Opacity[0.9], 
    EdgeForm[None], ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b}, {0, 0, 1}]}}}
```

Altogether

```
visualizeEllipsoid[{a_, b_, c_}, {o1_String: "X", o2_String: "Y", 
   o3_String: "Z"}, arrowstyle_: {}, col_: Black, n1_: 2, 
  n2_: 2.5] := {labelAxes[{a, b, c}, {o1, o2, o3}, col, n2], 
  arrowAxes[{a, b, c}, arrowstyle, n1], ellipsoidXYZ[{a, b, c}]}
```

A plane in 3D.

```
plane = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[], 
    FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.7]], 
    Cuboid[{-13, -6, 0.001}, {13, 6, 0.001}]}];
```

The ellipsoid

```
gr = Graphics3D[visualizeEllipsoid[{10, 3, 2}, {}, Red, Red], 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Application of `EulerRotationIllustration` taken from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fynyt.png)

```
$scene = First@gr;

EulerRotationIllustration[{\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_}, {a_, b_, 
   c_}] := Map[
  Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[$scene, #], PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    BoxStyle -> LightGray] &, {EulerMatrix[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}], 
   EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], 0, 0}, {a, b, c}], 
   EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], 0}, {a, b, c}], 
   EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}, {a, b, c}]}]

rotEuler = EulerRotationIllustration[{Pi/3, Pi/2, Pi/3}, {3, 1, 3}];
```

[image]

I am close...but not so close:-!)

The questions now:

1) How I can insert these curve arrows representing the angle of rotation?

2) How to modify the function `EulerRotationIllustration` (or use someting other) in order to depict the axis system that accompanies each rotation;

3) Is it possible to put different labels for each of these system (e.g. XYZ->x'y'z'->x''y''z''->xyz)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957)?

Comment: @J.M.: Not yet:-)!

Comment: I found this question (and the references therein) very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we are:-)! Not perfect; but still it's better than nothing.
I use the code from the [demonstration of Euler Angles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulerAngles/) (whenever I use it I make a reference).

For anyone interested in, I have splitted the solution in order to be more accessible. I realize also that it is very difficult (at least to me) to reach the initial desired generality.

```
(*axes and labels*)
 arrowAxes[{axesLength1_, axesLength2_, axesLength3_}, 
      arrowcolor_: Black] := {arrowcolor, Arrowheads[.05], 
      Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 0.04]] &, {axesLength1 + 0.5, 
         axesLength2 + 0.6, axesLength3 + 0.7} IdentityMatrix[3]]}
    labelAxes[{axesLength1_, axesLength2_, axesLength3_}, {o1_String: "x",
        o2_String: "y", o3_String: "z"}, 
      col_: Black] := {col, {Text[
        Style[o1, 20, Italic], {axesLength1 + 0.5, 0, -0.4}], 
       Text[Style[o2, 20, Italic], {0, axesLength2 + 1, -0.4}], 
       Text[Style[o3, 20, Italic], {0.1, 0.5, axesLength3 + 0.6}]}}

(*the global and local coodinate systems*)

axes1 = Graphics3D[{arrowAxes[{11, 10, 9}], 
    labelAxes[{11, 10, 9}, {}]}, ImageSize -> Large];
axes2 = Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[{arrowAxes[{11, 10, 11}, Red], 
     labelAxes[{11, 10.5, 11}, {"\[Xi]", "\[Eta]", "\[Zeta]"}, Red]}, 
    EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 3}]], ImageSize -> Large];
axes3 = Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[{arrowAxes[{13.5, 10, 11}, Blue], 
     labelAxes[{14.4, 10, 12}, {"\[Xi]'", "\[Eta]'", "\[Zeta]'"}, 
      Blue]}, EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, Pi/3, 0}, {3, 1, 3}]], 
   ImageSize -> Large];
axes4 = Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[{arrowAxes[{13, 11, 14}, Green], 
     labelAxes[{13.5, 11, 16}, {"\[Xi]'", "\[Eta]'", "\[Zeta]'"}, 
      Green]}, EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3}, {3, 1, 3}]], 
   ImageSize -> Large];
axesAll = Show[{axes1, axes2, axes3, axes4}]
```

[image]

```
(*arcs for rotation angles*)
(*code adopted from the demostration; slightly modified to fit my needs*)
phi = Pi/3; theta = Pi/3; psi = Pi/3;
xi = RotationMatrix[phi, {0, 0, 1}].{1, 0, 0};
eta = RotationMatrix[phi, {0, 0, 1}].{0, 1, 0};
zeta = RotationMatrix[phi, {0, 0, 1}].{0, 0, 1};
xiprime = RotationMatrix[theta, xi].xi;
etaprime = RotationMatrix[theta, xi].eta;
zetaprime = RotationMatrix[theta, xi].zeta;
etheta = RotationMatrix[theta/2, xi].zeta;
epsi = RotationMatrix[psi/2, zetaprime].xiprime;
phiarc = Table[
   11 RotationMatrix[tx, {0, 0, 1}].{1, 0, 0}, {tx, 0, 
    Max[Pi/3, 0.01], 0.05}];
thetaarc = 
 Table[10 RotationMatrix[tx, xi].zeta, {tx, 0, Max[Pi/3, 0.01], 
   0.05}]; psiarc = 
 Table[9 RotationMatrix[tx, zetaprime].xiprime, {tx, 0, 
   Max[Pi/3, 0.01], 0.05}];

angles = Graphics3D[{Text[
     Style["\[Phi]", FontSize -> 30, Red], {12 Cos[phi/2], 
      12 Sin[phi/2], 0}],
    Text[Style["\[Theta]", FontSize -> 30, Blue], 11 etheta],
    Text[Style["\[Psi]", FontSize -> 30, Green], 10 epsi]}];

arcs = {Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[Large], 
     Arrow[Tube[phiarc, 0.03]]}],
   Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrowheads[Large], 
     Arrow[Tube[thetaarc, 0.03]]}],
   Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[Tube[psiarc, 0.03]]}]};

Show[{axesAll, arcs, angles}]
```

[image]

```
(*ellipse to 3D; see reply to post 99958*)
ellipse3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radii_: {1, 1}, normal_: {0, 0, 1}] := 
 Polygon[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre][
   Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &][
    SortBy[#, N[ArcTan @@ (# - Most@centre)] &] &[
     MeshCoordinates[
      BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ellipsoid[Most@centre, radii]]]]]]]

(*non rotated elipsoid*)
ellipsoidXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}, opac1_: 0.6, 
  opac2_: 0.9] := {{Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[opac1], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}, {{Red, Opacity[opac2], 
    EdgeForm[None], ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {c, b}, {1, 0, 0}]}, {Blue, 
    Opacity[opac2], EdgeForm[None], 
    ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {a, c}, {0, 1, 0}]}, {Orange, Opacity[opac2],
     EdgeForm[None], ellipse3D[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b}, {0, 0, 1}]}}}

(*xy-plane*)
plane = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[], 
    FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.7]], 
    Cuboid[{-10 - 3, -6, 0.001}, {10 + 3, 6, 0.001}]}];

g1 = Show[{Graphics3D[ellipsoidXYZ[{9, 3, 2}]], axes1, plane}, 
  ImageSize -> Large];

g2 = Show[{Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[ellipsoidXYZ[{9, 3, 2}, 0.3], 
     EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 3}]]], 
   Graphics3D[angles[[1, 1]]], arcs[[1]], axes2, axes1, plane}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]

g3 = Show[{Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[ellipsoidXYZ[{9, 3, 2}, 0.3, 0.6], 
     EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, Pi/3, 0}, {3, 1, 3}]]], 
   Graphics3D[angles[[1, 1]]], Graphics3D[angles[[1, 2]]], arcs[[1]], 
   arcs[[2]], axes2, axes3, axes1, plane}, ImageSize -> Large]

g4 = Show[{Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[ellipsoidXYZ[{9, 3, 2}, 0.3, 0.6], 
     EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3}, {3, 1, 3}]]], 
   Graphics3D[angles[[1, 1]]], Graphics3D[angles[[1, 2]]], 
   Graphics3D[angles[[1, 3]]], arcs[[1]], arcs[[2]], arcs[[3]], axes2,
    axes3, axes1, axes4, plane}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]