# Insert a circle graphics in ListPlot and distinction minima with different colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

There is [my list](http://pastebin.com/f0NGFXfj) and I have used of

```
question = Show[{With[{cf = 
  Blend[{RGBColor[0.0, 0, 0.2], RGBColor[0.0, 0.5, 0.05]}, #] &}, 
ListPlot3D[list1, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0.1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Column[{Spacer[2], Style["n1", 15, Italic]}], 
   Row[{Style["n2", 15, Italic], Spacer[2]}], 
   Row[{Style["Crossing", 15, Italic], Spacer[10]}]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0.2], Thick], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14, Bold, Thickness[0.003]], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 ViewPoint -> {1.8760089184474407`, 3.6739174665092644`, 
   4.064839601655127`}, ViewVertical -> {0.0`, 0.0`, 1.0`}, 
 BoxStyle -> {Thickness[0.002]}, Mesh -> 11, MeshStyle -> Gray, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 500]]}]
```

To plot my list, but I should show at this plot a line which is apparently governs on the minima of data although these minima is restricted in a special area of plot not all minima, for example the desired minima are shown by red however undesired minima shown by Yellow. also I must show at `{n1=2.0,n2=0.2}` a circle as below, But I could not use of Epilog for inserting a circle moreover I am not able to distinct between desired and undesired minima from each others by different colors.
I would be so glad to hear any comment or key or answer.

[image]

Comment: Why not use `Sphere[]` as a marker, instead of a circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can just find the minimum for every point for n1 between 0 and 1, and plot those as a line,

```
(*Thanks to Taiki for the circle3D function*)

circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, 
   angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] := 
  Composition[Line, 
    Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &, 
    Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &, 
    Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &, Level[#, {-2}] &, 
    MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &, DiscretizeRegion, If][
   First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, Circle[Most@centre, radius], 
   Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]];

(*Import your list*)
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/f0NGFXfj";


plot = ListPlot3D[list1,
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0.0, 0, 0.2], 
        RGBColor[0.0, 0.5, 0.05]}, #] &),
   Mesh -> 11, MeshStyle -> Gray,
   AxesLabel -> {Column[{Spacer[2], Style["n1", 15, Italic]}], 
     Row[{Style["n2", 15, Italic], Spacer[2]}], 
     Row[{Style["Crossing", 15, Italic], Spacer[10]}]},
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0.2], Thick],
   TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 14, Bold, Thickness[0.003]], 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"]];
(* Generate the line by finding the minimum point along the line \
n1=x, where x runs from 0 to 1 *)

line = First@SortBy[#, (Last[#] &)] & /@ 
   Table[(Select[list1, #[[1]] == x &]), {x, 0, 1, .1}];

Show[plot,
 Graphics3D[{Directive[Red, Thick], Line@line}], 
 Graphics3D[{Directive[Blue, Thick], 
   circle3D[First@Select[list1, Most@# == {2.0, 0.2} &], .1]}],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1,
 ViewPoint -> {1.876, 3.67, 4.06},
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
 BoxStyle -> {Thickness[0.002]},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5},
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

I use [`circle3D`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79793/9490) to generate the circle.

The jagged point in the line is from the data itself,

```
ListLinePlot[{Rest /@ (Select[list1, #[[1]] == .4 &]),
  Rest /@ (Select[list1, #[[1]] == .5 &]),
  Rest /@ (Select[list1, #[[1]] == .6 &])}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[{"n1 = ", #}] & /@ {.4, .5, .6}),
 AxesLabel -> {"n2", "Crossing"}, BaseStyle -> 18]
```

[image]

So you can fudge the result if you wish, by replacing the offending data point with the average of the two nearby minima,

```
Show[plot,
 Graphics3D[{Directive[Red, Thick], 
   Line@ReplacePart[
     line, {6, 2} -> Mean[{line[[5, 2]], line[[7, 2]]}]]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Directive[Blue, Thick], 
   circle3D[First@Select[list1, Most@# == {2.0, 0.2} &], .1]}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, ViewPoint -> {1.876, 3.67, 4.06}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, BoxStyle -> {Thickness[0.002]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Besides so much thanks for valuable answer, but I think interpolation causes some fluctuations on the red line.

Comment: @Ackaran - that is from the data.  I removed the interpolation function and it is still there.  If you want to manually smooth it, that is up to you.

Comment: You are compeletly right

Comment: @Ackaran, let me know if that answered your question, or if there's anything else you need.

Comment: Your answer was so helpful and complete.

Comment: Your Updated answer does so faster work