# Smoothing the Sharp Undesired Points in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a large list at [list3](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=34739724578495086979),
when I use of `ListPlot3D` list, I face to some undesired points which are sharp and caused by calculation error. I want to replace them with the best value in order to have a smooth plot without any sharps points. If my data was short I could correct them manually but the list is very large and I am not able correct them by hand. Is there any way to correct automatically them. I have seen `LinearModelFit` or `Most` in some posts but they don't work correctly.

Just for showing the main question I am bringing the plot below. But my plot must be created after some processes recommended by Jason B (with so much thanks to him) at [process for plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107558/insert-a-circle-graphics-in-listplot-and-distinction-minima-with-different-color)

[image]

Comment: I have to leave for the day, but you might have some luck tracking down the outliers by looking at `ListPlot[Differences@list3[[All, 3]], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: A quick hack, but not really a solution, rather a starting point: `MedianFilter[list3, {1, 0}]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for single point anomalies `MedianFilter` (per comment from @kirma) with a little tweaking does a nice job,
(This assumes your data is on a regular grid)

```
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Sin[2 y] + 10 Boole[RandomReal[1] < .001], {x, -Pi, 
    Pi, .1}, {y, -Pi, Pi, .1}];
ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

first smooth the data:

```
smoothed = MedianFilter[data, 1];
```

then use the smoothed data as a filter, plot original points, except where the `MedianFilter` made a big change consider that an outlier and plot the median filtered value:

```
ListPlot3D[
 MapThread[If[Abs[#1 - #2] < 5, #1, #2] &, {data, smoothed} , 2]]
```

[image]

Edit: example using a flattened `{{xi,yi,zi},..}` data structure:

```
n = 60; m = 50
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x] Sin[2 y] + 10 Boole[RandomReal[1] < .001]},
    {x, -Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/(n - 1)},
    {y, -Pi, Pi, 2 Pi/(m - 1)}], 1];
```

verify input data is on a rectangular grid, and get width:

```
Flatten[grid = Table[{x, y},
    {x, SortBy[Union@data[[All, 1]], N]},
    {y, SortBy[Union@data[[All, 2]], N]}], 1] ==
 data[[All, {1, 2}]]
n = Dimensions[grid][[2]]
```

> True
>
> 50

```
smoothed = Flatten@MedianFilter[Partition[data[[All, 3]], n], 1];
ListPlot3D[MapThread[If[Abs[#1[[3]] - #2] < 5, #1,
    Append[#1[[;; 2]], #2]] &, {data, smoothed}]]
```

Comment: Smooth data of my real list is too abnormal. I can plot smooth of your table  but for my list it is completely destroyed.

Comment: @george2079 - do you mind if I edit this answer to show Ackaran exactly how to apply this to his data?  It works great, much better than the manual method I was trying.

Comment: @Jason B, I had used of smoothed = MedianFilter[list3, 1]; but this function destroyed my data in a amazing shape!!!1

Comment: The point is that your data **is** on a regular grid, but you have it arranged as a list of `{x, y, z}` points.  To make this method work (and it works fantastically), you first need to arrange your z values in a rectangular array.  Then apply the `MedianFilter`, then use the `MapThread` method but using a lmuch lower threshold than 5 - since your outliers are only larger than their expected values by a small amount.  Then you can take the resulting array and reshape it back to a list of `{x, y, z}` tuples.

Comment: I think I could understand what you mentioned. I must apply this function to just z values firstly.

Comment: @Ackaran, it can be written like `list3smooth = With[{list3b = Partition[Last /@ list3, 111]},
   Transpose[{list3[[All, 1]], list3[[All, 2]], 
     Flatten@MapThread[
       If[Abs[#1 - #2] < .01, #1, #2] &, {list3b, 
        MedianFilter[list3b, 1]}, 2]}
    ]];`

Comment: Or, in prettier formatting, here:  http://pastebin.com/raw/Mq1WwM8g

Comment: @Ackaran - were you able to solve your issue using the method in george2079's answer?  If so you should mark this question as solved