# How to make a 3D plot of light intensity for an image of a rectangular diffraction pattern?

Tags: plotting, image-processing

A point source of light passing through a rectangular aperture causes a diffraction pattern that is a extension of a single single diffraction pattern (In that the pattern appears in 2 axes).

[image]

The pattern that is observed is as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to create a 3D plot for the intensity of light. With the origin at the center of the diffraction pattern, from the image.

Something like this.

[image]

I know how to create a 2D intensity graph for the case of single slit diffraction. But that is using Tracker and not Mathematica. How can I make this 3D plot using Mathematica?

*Also I haven't done image processing of this kind with Mathematica before. Am I supposed to pre-edit the image in any way or just use the raw image from the camera?*

Thanks for any and all help.

EDIT: Another question I just thought of. How can I extract the values for intensity for the maximas from the image?

Comment: Something like `ListPlot3D[ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel@ColorConvert[img,"Grayscale"]], PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", DataRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]`  might be a worthwhile start?

Comment: This is really good. Do you know how I can get the intensity values for the maximas. I'm not sure how to extract it from the image.

Comment: You should linearize colorspace in order to get real *physical* intencity values. More info: "[The correct way to linearize colorspace before resizing, blurring etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/280)", also see the "UPDATE" section of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86441/280) answer.

Comment: Thanks I will read this sounds interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O5xI.png"];

intensity = First @ Values @ ComponentMeasurements[image, "IntensityData"]; 

intensityarray = ArrayReshape[intensity, Reverse @ ImageDimensions @ image];

ListPlot3D[intensityarray, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

`"IntensityData"` seems to be the same as `GrayLevel` value when we remove the alpha channel from the input image and `ColorConvert` the image to `GrayLevel`:

```
intensityarrayb = ImageData[ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel@image, GrayLevel]]; 

intensityarray == intensityarrayb
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks this is great! Do you know how I can get the values of intensity for each of the maixmas from that image. Also what is the unit for this intensity. I've tried searching online I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal, `"IntensityData"`  for a pixel seems to be gray level value (a value b/w 0 and 1).  Yoy can use `MaxDetect`  on `intensityarray` (e.g., `MaxDetect[intensityarray, .1] //Colorize`) to identify the local  _maximas_.

Answer (score 2):

I took your grayscale pattern and did following:

```
a = ImageData@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O5xI.png"];
ListPlot3D[MovingAverage[b[[All, All, 1]], 6], 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 320}, {5, 320}, All}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The `MovingAverage` was used to make the background noise of your image a bit softer. The [[All,All,1]] after `b` were used because the initial image contains alfa-channel..

Comment: Does this give quantitative measurements? Any idea how I can extract out this information for the maxima values.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal, I took your picture, man, and just have redrawn it in 3D as you ask. It is evidently not a correct physical data because zero order of diffraction is too weak . I guess, it is manually suppressed for nice view of the higher orders. You should solve the diffraction problem for your case to obtain the physically correct data about real amplitudes of orders.

Comment: Yup I'll do that thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal, actually, the simple model of diffraction for any hole can be done very easy - you just need to make a summation of complex amplitudes of spherical waves (that sit on the outer face of the slit) at the desired plane after the slit.

Comment: I have found the analytical formula for intensity of this case. Which was $I(x,y) \propto sinc^{2} \left ( \frac{\pi Wx}{\lambda z} \right ) sinc^{2} \left ( \frac{\pi Hy}{\lambda z} \right )$. However I was looking to try and verify it via observation as well. I think I can get those values for intensity using Tracker so it should be fine.

Comment: You can also do `RemoveAlphaChannel[ColorConvert[img, "GrayScale"]]` instead of `b[[All, All, 1]]` as I showed in my comment - it really just depends on how clear you want your code to be.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal, This solution is close enough to reality. The zero order should be about 5-10 times higher than the first one. However, the picture with correct ratio `I1/I0` will looks too ugly and mostly it is drawn so that `I0~I1`.

Answer (score 1):

For quantitative measurements mentioned in comments of previois answers:

`i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYVTC.png"]`

[image]

Not a great attempt at cleaning up the image:

```
i0 = Rasterize[RemoveBackground[RemoveBackground[ImageMultiply[i, MaxDetect[i, 0.6]]], Black],Background -> Black]
```

[image]

You can identify all the max intenisty points of each section:

```
markers = MaxDetect[i0, Padding -> 1];
HighlightImage[i0, markers, Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 5}]
```

[image]

Measure the max intesity of each segment:

```
ComponentMeasurements[i0, "MaxIntensity"]
```

If you explore `ComponentMeasurements[]` there is a bunch of nice stuff you can measure and plot.

```
out[1]: {1 -> 0.407843, 2 -> 0.372549, 3 -> 0.380392,...}
```

Stealing Rom38's 3D code:

```
a = ImageData@i0;
ListPlot3D[MovingAverage[a[[All, All, 1]], 6], 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 320}, {5, 320}, All}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

I think  you can use a median filter like this, if you would like a smoother graph as in your original post

[Smoothing the Sharp Undesired Points in ListPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107593/smoothing-the-sharp-undesired-points-in-listplot3d)

Comment: Thanks this is really good.