# Plotting disk in 3D at given spherical angles

Tags: plotting

Edit: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79524/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-3d-on-a-sphere) has very useful answers, but none address how to work with spherical coordinates.

---

I want to plot a 2D disk in 3D space, angled perpendicular to a given direction. That direction is given by $\theta$ and $\phi$ in spherical coordinates (where $\theta$ is polar and $\phi$ is azimuthal cause I'm a physicist, sorry math people!).

Here's four approaches I've tried that nearly work but not quite:

1. `ContourPlot3D` in cartesian coordinates

   ```
   ContourPlot3D[{x + y + z == 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
   ```

   This gives an inclined plane, but I can't figure out how to put it at the desired angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. I also wouldn't know how to make this a disk with a finite radius.

   [image]
2. `ContourPlot3D` in spherical coordinates, by converting x+y+z==1 into spherical

   ```
   ContourPlot3D[{r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] + r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] 
        + r*Cos[θ] == 1},
   {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
   ```

   This uses {r,$\theta$,$\phi$} as the plot coordinates, rather than plotting in proper cartesian space.

   [image]
3. `ParametricPlot3D` to make a disk, then rotate it

   ```
   ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕ],r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕ], r*Cos[Pi/2]},
     {r, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
   ```

   This can produce a disk, but I can't figure out how to angle it. Here I set $\theta$=$\pi$/2 to make the disk.

   [image]
4. Use `Disk` with `Graphics3D` and `Rotate`

   This would work if `Disk` could be used as a 3D object! Argh!

---

That's all my ideas. If you see how to fix one of these, or have another, better idea, please advise!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79524/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-3d-on-a-sphere/79793#79793) by [Taiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5906/taiki).

Comment: Some of the techniques used to create a 3D circle are certainly relevant for creating a 3D disk, but I don't think that makes this question a duplicate, especially since what I consider the best answer to that question uses BSplineCurve, and a BSplineCurve is not capable of creating a disk. I just created a resource function [Disk3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Disk3D) based on BSplineSurface that can create a 3D disk, so I think it makes sense to reopen this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define the normal in spherical coordinates:

```
n[theta_, phi_] := {Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], Sin[theta]*Sin[phi], Cos[theta]}
```

Then multiply your (syntax-corrected) `ParametricPlot3D` with `RotationMatrix` and wrap it in `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
     ParametricPlot3D[
       RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, n[theta, phi]}].  
         {r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[Phi], r*Sin[Pi/2] Sin[Phi], r*Cos[Pi/2]}
         , {r, 0, 1}, {Phi, 0, 2*Pi}
         , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
         , AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
      , Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, n[theta, phi]}]}]]
  , {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, {phi, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you. RotationMatrix was the missing piece to my idea #3 above. Small note: typically theta goes 0->Pi and phi goes 0->2Pi.

Answer (score 3):

Given the normal vector

```
n={Cos[\[Theta]] Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]],Sin[\[Theta]]}
```

the plane orthogonal to n is given by

```
e={Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], -Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], 0}
f={-Cos[\[CurlyPhi]] Sin[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi]],Cos[\[Theta]]}
```

The 3D-disk can be plotted using

```
Block[{\[Theta] = 50 \[Degree], \[CurlyPhi] = 10 \[Degree] },
Show[{Graphics3D[{Point[{0, 0, 0}], Opacity[.2], Sphere[]}], 
ParametricPlot3D [r (Cos[t] e + Sin[t] f), {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]}, Boxed-> False]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with you answer, but @anderstood built upon one of my solutions which made it easier for me to work with. Small feedback: aren't your n and e defined the same?

Comment: Sorry, cut &paste error: I edited my answer.

Comment: ...  `n!=e`:  By the way  I didn't agree, that using a RotationMatrix is easier than the evaluation of two orthogonal vectors...

Answer (score 3):

The resource function [Disk3D](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Disk3D) generates a [`BSplineSurface`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineSurface) representation of a 3D disk. For example, a 3D disk with symmetry axis in the direction `{1, 1, 1}`:

```
Graphics3D @ ResourceFunction["Disk3D"][{0,0,0}, 1, {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

A 3D elliptical disk in the plane spanned by `{1, 1, 0}` and `{0, 1, 1}` with the semimajor axis in the direction `{1, 1, 0}`:

```
Graphics3D[{
    ResourceFunction["Disk3D"][{0, 0, 0}, {3, 1}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}], 
    Red, Arrow[{{0,0,0}, {1,1,0}}],
    Blue, Arrow[{{0,0,0}, {0,1,1}}]
}]
```

[image]

A graphic with many disks:

```
Graphics3D[{
    LightGreen,
    MapThread[
        ResourceFunction["Disk3D"],
        {RandomReal[10, {300, 3}], RandomReal[3, 300], RandomReal[1, {300, 3}]}
    ]
}]
```

[image]

An example of the [`BSplineSurface`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineSurface) primitive:

```
ResourceFunction["Disk3D"][{0,0,0}]
```

> BSplineSurface[{{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, {{-1, 1, 0}, {1/9, 0, 
>       0}, {1, -1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}, 
>    SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}}, 
>    SplineWeights -> {{1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}}]