# ItoProcess for 3 coupled SDEs sourced by 5 Wiener processes

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

**Context**

I am trying to solve a stochastic equation corresponding to Vector resonant relaxation (the way orbital planes of stars diffuse near the galactic center,
see below).

### [image]

**Setup**

Within the context of some approximation, the orientation vector of the plane of the orbit $\hat{\mathbf{L}}$ obeys

[image]

where $\mathbf{M}$ is a stochastic matrix of the form

[image]

which I have implemented in Mathematica as (assuming $\Gamma_t=1$)

```
Format[em2] = Subscript[e, -2]; Format[em1] = Subscript[e, -1];
Format[e2] = Subscript[e, 2];
Format[e1] = Subscript[e, 1];
Format[e0] = Subscript[e, 0]; Format[u1] = Subscript[u, 1]; 
Format[u2] = Subscript[u, 2]; Format[u3] = Subscript[u, 3];

M = {{DifferentialD[e2][t], 
   DifferentialD[em2][t], -DifferentialD[e1][t]}, {DifferentialD[em2][
    t], -DifferentialD[e2][t], -DifferentialD[em1][
     t]}, {-DifferentialD[e1][t], -DifferentialD[em1][
     t], Sqrt[3] DifferentialD[e0][t]}}
```

Then I can define $\hat{ \mathbf{L}}$ as

```
L = #[t] & /@ {u1, u2, u3};
eqn = \[DifferentialD]#[t] & /@ {u1, u2, u3} == Cross[L, M.L] // Apart // Thread;
eqn // TableForm
```

[image]

So that the `ItoProcess` obeys

```
proc = ItoProcess[
  eqn, {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t]}, {{u1, u2, u3}, {1, 1/2, 1/3}}, t,
  {e2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   em2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   e1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   em1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   e0 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]
```

[image]

I can then compute a set of paths as

```
path = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 1., 0.01}, Method -> "StochasticRungeKutta"]
ListLinePlot[path]
```

[image]

---

**Question**

> Why is it not returning random paths?

*Let me apologize in advance for what is likely to be a stupid mistake on my part.*

---

**Astrophysical context**

In the vicinity of a supermassive black hole, stars move on nearly Keplerian orbits. Yet, because of the enclosed stellar mass and relativistic corrections, the potential slightly deviates from the Keplerian one, which causes the stellar orbits to precess. Similarly, as a result of the finite number of stars, the mutual gravitational torques between pairs of stars also drive a rapid reshuffling of the stars' orbital orientations. Overall, the combination of these two effects leads to a stochastic evolution of stellar orbital angular momentum vectors, through a process named 'resonant relaxation'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typographic error is in the definition of the matrix

```
M = {{DifferentialD[e2[t]], 
   DifferentialD[em2[t]], -DifferentialD[e1[t]]}, {DifferentialD[
    em2[t]],
   -DifferentialD[e2[t]], -DifferentialD[em1[t]]}, {-DifferentialD[
     e1[t]], -DifferentialD[em1[t]], Sqrt[3] DifferentialD[e0[t]]}}
```

i.e. it should involve `DifferentialD[e2[t]]` or `\[DifferentialD]e2[t]` not `DifferentialD[e2][t]`.

[image]

Since for this problem the noise needs to be correlated (see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219575/1089)),
it is in fact simpler to rely on `NDSolve` together with [GaussianRandomField](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166555/1089)

```
nn = 1024*2; tmax = 2*25; Amp = 5;
noise = Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline"][t] & /@ 
   Table[Transpose@{tmax Range[0, nn - 1]/(nn - 1) // N,
      GaussianRandomField[nn, 1, Function[k, k^-0.5]] Amp}, {5}];
eqn2 = eqn /. {\[DifferentialD]e0[t] -> 
      noise[[1]], \[DifferentialD]e1[t] -> 
      noise[[2]], \[DifferentialD]em1[t] -> 
      noise[[3]], \[DifferentialD]e2[t] -> 
      noise[[4]], \[DifferentialD]em2[t] -> 
      noise[[5]]} /.
   {\[DifferentialD]u1[t] -> 
     u1'[t], \[DifferentialD]u2[t] -> 
     u2'[t], \[DifferentialD]u3[t] -> u3'[t]};
eqn2 = Join[eqn2, {u1[0] == 1, u2[0] == 0, u3[0] == 0}];
sol[t_] = NDSolveValue[eqn2, {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Then

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[ sol[t], {t, 0, tmax}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

One can represent explicitly the orbital planes via this function

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, 
  angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] := 
 Composition[Tube, 
   Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &, 
   Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &, 
   Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &, Level[#, {-2}] &, 
   MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &, DiscretizeRegion, If][
  First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, Circle[Most@centre, radius], 
  Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]]
```

from that [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79793/1089). Then

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Thick, 
   Table[circle3D[{0, 0, 0}, i, sol[i]], {i, 0, 1, 0.05}]}, 
  Boxed -> False], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]