# Ito Process sourced by Gaussian Process?

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, random-process

**Question**

> Is it possible to extend the function `ItoProcess` so that it takes correlated noise?

I.e  would like to be able to write

```
 eqn = Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == 1/10 {-y[t], x[t]} + {n1[t], n2[t]}];
 proc = ItoProcess[eqn, {x[t], y[t]}, {{x, y}, {1, 1}}, t, {n1 \[Distributed] GaussianProcess[],  n2 \[Distributed] GaussianProcess[]}];
```

as a means of solving a Stochastic Differential Equation sourced by *correlated* random noise. So I would like to have a function called `GaussianProcess`
and that `ItoProcess` understands it. (If I understand correctly the Documentation `WienerProcess` is uncorrelated).

> Is it quite possible this functionality exists with a different name?

**Attempt**

I know how to do this using the `GaussianRandomField` (defined in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4916/1089)) and `NDSolve`

```
 noise = Interpolation[#][t] & /@ Table[GaussianRandomField[256, 1, Function[k, k^-2]] // Chop, {2}];
 Plot[noise, {t, 1, 256}];
```

[image]

(Note the level of correlation in the noise)

After interpolation, I can integrate using `NDSolveValue`

```
eqn = Thread[{x'[t], y'[t]} == 1/10 {-y[t], x[t]} + noise];
eqn = Join[eqn, {x[1] == 1, y[1] == 1}];
sol = NDSolveValue[eqn, {x, y}, {t, 1, 256}];
ParametricPlot[#[t] & /@ sol, {t, 1, 256}]
```

[image]

(amusing random plot!)

Yet, it would be great IMHO if a function like `GaussianProcess` existed and could be fed to the `ItoProcess` framework.

**Motivation**

One advantage of such solution would be to inherit all the wrapping that 
`ItoProcess` has, while being able to specify the exact PowerSpectrum of the Gaussian noise.

PS: For clarity, let me replicate here the `GaussianRandomField`  function that @HenrikSchumacher wrote

```
GaussianRandomField[
  size : (_Integer?Positive) : 256, dim : (_Integer?Positive) : 1, 
  Pk_: Function[k, k^-3]] := Module[{Pkn, fftIndgen, noise, amplitude, s2},
  s2 = Quotient[size, 2];
  fftIndgen = N@ArrayPad[Range[0, s2], {0, s2 - 1}, "ReflectedNegation"];
  amplitude = Sqrt[Outer[Plus, Sequence@@ ConstantArray[fftIndgen^2, dim],dim]];
  amplitude[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, dim]]] = 1.;
  amplitude = Pk[amplitude];
  amplitude[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, dim]]] = 0.;
  noise = Fourier[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], ConstantArray[size, dim]]];
  Re[InverseFourier[noise amplitude]]
  ]
```

Note that this code provides the opportunity to generate correlated Gaussian Random Processes,

```
 tt = GaussianRandomField[128, 2];tt[[;; , ;; 8]] // Transpose // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

which could be handy.

**Complement**

As a possible wrapper to `GaussianRandomField`  one could define

```
Clear[gaussianProcess, GaussianProcess];
gaussianProcess[R : (_?Positive) : 1, L : (_?Positive) : 10, 
  dx : (_?Positive) : 1/100, nb : (_Integer?Positive) : 1] := 
 Module[{tt, k, nn}, 
  If[dx > R/2, Print["Insufficient Sampling"]; Abort[]];
  tt = Table[tt = GaussianRandomField[nn = Round[L/dx];
      nn = If[OddQ[nn], nn + 1, nn], 1, 
      Function[k, Exp[-1/2 R^2 (2 Pi k/L)^2]]];
    tt /= StandardDeviation[tt], {nb}];
  If[nb == 1, tt = tt[[1]]];
  TemporalData[tt, {0., L}, 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
     Method -> "Spline"}]];    
   GaussianProcess /: 
   RandomFunction[ GaussianProcess[R_], {0, t1_, dt_}, n_: 1] := 
    gaussianProcess[R, t1, dt, n]
```

Then `RandomFunction` produces the timelines as it does with `WienerProcess`.

```
  dat = RandomFunction[GaussianProcess[0.1], {0, 20, 0.01}, 5]
```

[image]

The next difficult step is to tell `ItoProcess` to take `GaussianProcess` 
as a legitimate argument.

Comment: It seems an interesting problem. But I guess it would be better if some notes briefing the theoretical fundamentals are provided.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a solution, but some comparison two different approach to the same problem (oscillator with random force). What we expecting from `ItoProcess` in this case? We looking for model of force, and there are several possibilities for `ItoProcess` as option for process. There are also several method of solution. Nevertheless there is one combination similar to the possible solution:

```
ito = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[
      t] == -1/10 y[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w1[t]/
      15, \[DifferentialD]y[t] == 
    1/10 x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]w2[t]/15}, {x[t], 
   y[t]}, {{x, y}, {1, 1}}, 
  t, {w1 \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, .03, 1], 
   w2 \[Distributed] OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1, .03, 1]}];
 path = RandomFunction[ito, {1., 256, .05}, 1, Method -> "Milstein"];
 dat = Flatten[Transpose@path["ValueList"], 1];
 {ListLinePlot[path], 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/Length[dat]], Point[dat[[i]]]}, {i, 
    Length[dat]}], AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]