# Coupled stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am trying to solve the following coupled system of stochastic differential equations:

$\qquad \dot{x}(t)=y(t)\,\eta(t)$
$\qquad \dot{y}(t)=x(t)\,\eta(t)$

$x$ and $y$ are functions to be solved for and $\eta$ is a Wiener process.
I think this is a coupled Stratonovich process. I have read the documentation for Stratonovich processes, but it doesn't mention how to solve coupled Stratonovich processes.

I hope someone will be able to help me.

Comment: There are examples in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StratonovichProcess.html) under Scope->Basic uses.

Comment: oh. i skipped that part. thanks that solves the problem.

Comment: I have a mathematical question though: I saw some examples in the documentation and there can be terms which are like $x[t]dw[t]$. but from the equation I wrote shouldn't it be more like: $d(x[t]w[t])$?

Comment: Seems to be somewhat related to this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219515/itoprocess-for-3-coupled-sdes-sourced-by-5-wiener-processes

Comment: @chris yes that is very helpful. thanks