# Plot given points, lines and arcs in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

I need to plot 6 points in 3D. I used the command 'Plot' but I couldn't draw it.

1. The coordinates of points $A,A',B,B',C,C',D$ are given.
2. $AD,BD,CD$ are straight line segments
3. $AA',BB',CC'$ are arcs with known radius $r$ and centers $c_{0},c_{1},c_{2}$.

[image]

The coordinates are

```
A = {0, 0, 0}; B = {400, 0, 0} C = {200, 400, 200}; D = {226, 137, 62};
Aprime = {22, 36, 0}; Bprime = {382, 33, 0}; Cprime = {240, 357, 200};
c0 = {40, 0, 0}; c1 = {360, 0, 0}; c2 = {200, 360, 200}; 
r = 40;
```

Comment: Look up `Graphics3D[]`, `Point[]`, and `Line[]`. As for circle arcs, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10957).

Comment: gotta wonder why wolfram doesnt just generalize `Circle` to 3D.

Comment: @YvesKlett Coordinates are added in the question

Comment: See also [How to draw an ellipse arc in 3D?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6526/245)

Answer (score 4):

Relabeling to avoid conflict with in-bulit symbols:

```
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {400, 0, 0};
c = {200, 400, 200}; d = {226, 137, 62};
aprime = {22, 36, 0}; bprime = {382, 33, 0}; cprime = {240, 357, 200};
c0 = {40, 0, 0}; c1 = {360, 0, 0}; c2 = {200, 360, 200};
r = 40;
```

`arc` just to deal with desired arcs. `Sphere` for illustration.

```
arc[p1_, p2_, p3_, n_] := With[{v1 = p2 - p1, v2 = p3 - p1},
  Table[p1 + RotationMatrix[j, Cross[v1, v2]].v1, {j, 0, 
    VectorAngle[v1, v2], VectorAngle[v1, v2]/n}]]
```

I leave labeling and modification to OP.

```
Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{d, a}], Line[{d, b}], 
  Line[{d, c}], {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[#, 40]} & /@ {c0, c1, 
    c2}, {PointSize[0.02], Point@#} & /@ {a, b, c, aprime, bprime, 
    cprime}, {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@#} & /@ {c0, c1, 
    c2}, {Thick, Line[arc[c0, a, aprime, 10]], 
   Line[arc[c1, b, bprime, 10]], Line[arc[c2, c, cprime, 10]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ubpqdn. Thanks for that. Is that possible to remove Sphere's in the figure?

Comment: @Harry just remove from list of graphics objects, i.e. `Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{d, a}], Line[{d, b}], 
  Line[{d, c}], {PointSize[0.02], Point@#} & /@ {a, b, c, aprime, bprime, 
    cprime}, {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@#} & /@ {c0, c1, 
    c2}, {Thick, Line[arc[c0, a, aprime, 10]], 
   Line[arc[c1, b, bprime, 10]], Line[arc[c2, c, cprime, 10]]}}]`