# How can I create a graphic of a wedge of a cylinder (like a slice of pie)?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HoleInACylinder/

This demonstration uses `Graphics3D` and is able to generate what I want, but I cant figure out how to separate the simple cylinder plot from the interactive window code. I need to make a simple graphic with specific height, radius, and angle.

Likewise, is there a way to generate such a cylindrical wedge using an integral function with specified bounds to generate a volume? Any help is appreciated, I am brand new to *Mathematica* and I think this will be quick for someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: I made a function that can do that as part of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6535/245). It's called `ellipse3D`

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Speaking of "pie slices", you can use `SectorChart3D`  directly as follows:

```
ClearAll[sliceF]
sliceF[opts : OptionsPattern[]][x_, y_, r_: {0, 2}, h_: 2] := 
 SectorChart3D[{{(y - x) Degree, r[[2]], h}, {(360 - y + x) Degree , 
    r[[2]], h}}, SectorOrigin -> {{x Degree}, r[[1]]}, opts]

sliceF[BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True][30, 70]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sliceF[BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True][30, 70, {1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sliceF[BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True,  ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["ProfileSector3D", "Profile" -> 5]][30, 70, {3/2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

```
ClearAll[csF]
csF[opts : OptionsPattern[]][angle_: {0, Pi/2}, radii_: {0, 1}, 
  minmaxheight_: {0, 1}, style_: {EdgeForm[], Opacity[1], Orange}] := 
 Graphics3D[{## & @@ style, 
   ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"][{angle, radii, minmaxheight}, 0]}, opts]

csF[][{0, 3 Pi/4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
csF[Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400][{0, 3 Pi/4}, {.5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Panel@Row[csF[ Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 200][{0, #}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, 
  {EdgeForm[]}] & /@ (Pi {1/3,  3/2, 4/3})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Panel@Row[csF[ Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 200][{0, Pi/4}, {#, 1}, {0, 1},
   {EdgeForm[]}] & /@ ({0, 1/3, 2/3})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Panel@Row[csF[ Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> {0, 1}][{0, 
      Pi/4}, {0, 1}, {#, 1}, {EdgeForm[]}] & /@ ({0, 1/3, 2/3})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1,I always learn something...ChartElementData opens up a lot of potential value :)

Answer (score 5):

See if the following can give you a starting point:

```
radius = 3; height = 3; angle = 30 Degree;

RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 <= radius^2 && x >= 0 && 0 <= y <= ArcTan[angle] x && 0 <= z <= height,
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, height},
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05], Scaled[.1]},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]