# How can I create a graphic array of wedges of cylinders (slice of pie)?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions, image3d

I'm trying to create an array of wedges of cylinders. So far I have been able to create an array of a full cylinder as shown in the next figure:

[image]

Using the next code:

```
Show[Graphics3D[Table[With[{p = {.1, .3, .9}}, {RGBColor[p], Opacity[.75], 
 Cylinder[{{8 i, 8 j, 8 k}, {8 i, 8 j, 8 k + 20}}, 2.5]}], {i, 6}, {j, 6}, {k, 1}], Boxed -> False],
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], LightGray,Cuboid[{55, 55, 30}, {2, 2, 2}]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

I am also able to create the slice of cylinder using: [How can I create a graphic of a wedge of a cylinder (like a slice of pie)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112790/how-can-i-create-a-graphic-of-a-wedge-of-a-cylinder-like-a-slice-of-pie)

My main problem is the transition from one wedge of a cylinder to such a graphical array.

Thanks in advance!

Alan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a a single cylinder wedge using the function `sliceF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112815/125)

```
ClearAll[sliceF]
sliceF[opts : OptionsPattern[]][x_, y_, r_: {0, 2}, h_: 2] := 
 SectorChart3D[{{(y - x) Degree, r[[2]], h}, {(360 - y + x) Degree, 
    r[[2]], h}}, SectorOrigin -> {{x Degree}, r[[1]]}, opts]
```

and we can use [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) to get translated copies of it:

```
{innerradius, outerradius, height} = {0, 2.5, 20};
{startingangle, endingangle} = {10, 260};

wedge = sliceF[BoxRatios -> 1, 
    ChartStyle -> { RGBColor[.1, .3, .9, .75], Opacity[0]}, 
    Axes -> True][startingangle, endingangle, {innerradius, outerradius}, height]
```

[image]

```
translations = 8 Tuples[Range @ {6, 6, 1}]; 

Graphics3D[ {RGBColor[.1, .3, .9, .75], 
   Translate[wedge[[1]], translations], 
   Opacity[0.1], LightGray, Cuboid[{55, 55, 30}, {2, 2, 2}]},
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

We can also use `wedge` as `ChartElements` with `RectangleChart3D` to get a similar picture:

```
Show[RectangleChart3D[ConstantArray[{8, 8, 20}, {6, 6}], 
  ChartLayout -> "Grid",
  ChartElements -> wedge, 
  Method -> "Canvas" -> False,  
  Axes -> False, FaceGrids -> None] ,
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2, LightGray], 
   Scale[Cuboid[], {60, 60, 30}, {.1, .1, .1}]}], 
 Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will use it :)

Comment: @Alan,my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.