# Projecting a Graphics3D object onto a plane

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, intersection, geometric-transform

I would like to project a 3-dimensional cone onto a plane and mark the intersection (which is an ellipse) with a line. I find `cone2` by performing a transformation on `cone1`:

```
cone1 = Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}];
transform = {{0.3, 0, 0.15}, {0, 0.35, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0.5}};
cone2 = GeometricTransformation[cone1, transform];
```

Now I would like to project `cone2` through the origin onto the z = 1 plane. However, I cannot see a good way of directly performing this transformation in Mathematica. The best I can do is scale `cone2` and then cut the graphic off at z = 1, thus:

```
origin = Point[{0, 0, 0}];
projcone2 = Scale[cone2, 3, {0, 0, 0}];

Graphics3D[{
   {Opacity[0.25], EdgeForm[{Thick}], cone1},
   {Opacity[0.6], Magenta, EdgeForm[Thick], cone2},
   {Opacity[0.6], Cyan, EdgeForm[Thick], projcone2},
   {PointSize[Large], origin}},
   Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> 1]
```

This gives:

[image: cone2 projected onto cone1]

However, I would like the intersection of `projcone2` and the base of `cone1` to be marked with a line, just as the bases of `cone1` and `cone2` are. Possibly this could be achieved using [this ellipse3D function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-arc-in-3d). But finding the parameters that describe the ellipse in question is not entirely straightforward, and this whole method of scaling and cutting off seems like a bit of a hack anyway, so I would like to know if there is a better way.

I see that [nonlinear transformation of regions is possible](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/nonlinear-transformation-of-a-region.html) but have been unable to find anything for performing a nonlinear transformation on a 3D object.

## The question

How can I correctly find the object `projcone2` by implementing a transformation on `cone2`? By correctly, I mean that `projcone2` should be exactly the 3D region required that is bounded by the z = 1 plane without having to artificially cut the image off there. Then the above code `{Opacity[0.6], Cyan, EdgeForm[Thick], projcone2}` would automatically display the desired intersection ellipse.

Comment: Please make the "another issue" part a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, done. See [Unattractive streaky rendering of Graphics3D images](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120391/unattractive-streaky-rendering-of-graphics3d-images).

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could find to add the ellipse you are asking for to your graphic was to compute a set of points along the ellipse and make line segments from them. Here is how I did it.

The following generates the graphic you show int the question.

```
origin = Point[{0, 0, 0}];
cone1 = Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}];
transform = {{0.3, 0, 0.15}, {0, 0.35, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0.5}};
cone2 = GeometricTransformation[cone1, transform];
projcone2 = Scale[cone2, {2.99, 2.99, 3}, {0, 0, 0}];

g1 = 
  Graphics3D[
    {{Opacity[0.25], EdgeForm[{Thick}], cone1}, 
     {Opacity[0.6], Magenta, EdgeForm[Thick], cone2}, 
     {Opacity[0.6], Cyan, EdgeForm[{Thick}], projcone2}, 
     {PointSize[Large], origin}},
    Boxed -> False,
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
```

And this generates the requested ellipse.

```
projPt[sourcPt_] := 
  Normal[
    Scale[
      GeometricTransformation[Point[sourcPt], transform], 
      {2.99, 2.99, 3}, {0, 0, 0}]][[1]]

With[{n = 72},
  ellipse = 
    Module[{z, pts, pairs},
      pts =
        Table[(z = projPt[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 1}])/z[[3]], {u, Subdivide[0, 2 π, n]}];
      pairs = Partition[pts, 2, 1];
      {Thick, Line[pairs]}]];
```

Putting the two graphics together gives

```
Show[g1, Graphics3D[ellipse], 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, {.02, .006}},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: cones]

#### Update

The OP insists that intersection of cone3 with the plane `z == 1` be drawn as a distorted disk just so he can write something like

```
{Opacity[0.6], Cyan, EdgeForm[{Thick}], ellipse}
```

I will now demonstrate why I think that is a bad idea.

```
With[{n = 72},
  ellipse2 =
    Module[{pt, pts},
      pts =
       Table[(pt = projPt[{Cos[u], Sin[u], 1}])/pt[[3]], {u, Subdivide[0, 2 π, n]}];
      {Opacity[0.6], Cyan, EdgeForm[{Thick}], Polygon[pts]}]];

Show[cones, Graphics3D[ellipse2], 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, {.02, .006}},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: top_view]

Note: this is my final word on this subject. Seeing how it is of little interest to anyone but the OP, I have already spent too much time on it.

Comment: Thanks very much. However, possibly I should have made one point clearer in the question: ideally `projcone2` would have a base (as it would automatically if it could be generated by the appropriate transformation on `cone2`). Is it possible to fill in the ellipse you have plotted? (This would be possible using the `ellipse3d` solution I suggested in the question, if one could find the parameters that describe the ellipse.)

Comment: @Antony. Are you saying you want the `projcone2` to be a Mathematica `Cone` object. Not possible. All such objects are right circular cones by definition. `projcone2` as you want it to be (and not as you have defined it) could be constructed laboriously from as large collection of triangles or as a triangular mesh. Another approach would be to find the correct geometric tranformation from `cone1` into `projcone2`, but that is a math problem and not a Mathematica one. Perhaps you can solve that math problem.

Comment: I know that `projcone2` cannot be a `Cone` object, but I would like it to behave as if you could define it as such an object. This would mean that the intersection ellipse would automatically be described by a surface that could easily be filled in Mathematica, instead of it being defined just by its boundary. If that is not possible then is there a good way to fill in the interior of the ellipse given by your parametrisation of its boundary?