# How to draw a directed arc?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How to draw a directed arc with an initial point $(x_i,y_i)$, a terminal point $(x_t,y_t)$, and another given, intermediate point $(x_m,y_m)$ on the arc (say in the middle of the arc)? For instance, we may have $(x_i,y_i)=(0,0)$, $(x_t,y_t)=(2,0)$, and $(x_m,y_m)=(1,1/3)$.

I have noticed the nice answers to a [related problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132636/function-to-draw-a-3-point-arc). However, with my very limited proficiency in Mathematica, I do not see a good way to modify those answers to get what I need here. I can certainly draw an arc -- but how to attach an arrow to it nicely?

Comment: The documentation for `Arrow` gives examples of how to use Bezier curves to describe the path of an arrow, or a list of points.  I expect you could create a function to draw a directed arc based on one or other of those.  No *Mathematica* on this machine or I might have experimented a wee bit myself.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: `pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, 1/3}};` and `Graphics[Arrow[BezierCurve[pts]]]`.

Comment: @Syed : Thank you very much. Can you post this as an answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: It is directly from the docs. If you make the question more interesting, then I would be happy to try to solve it and post an answer.

Comment: see also: [How do I add arrowheads to circular arcs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13547/125)

Comment: @kglr : thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

With the hint from HighPerformanceMark, the answer is simple. For instance,

```
Graphics[{Arrowheads[.06],Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}}]]}]
```

yields

[image]

Comment: But this is not a circle arc. Compare with `pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1/3}, {2, 0}};
Graphics[{Circumsphere[pts], Point[pts], 
  Red, {Arrowheads[.06], 
   Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}]]}}]`

Comment: @cvgmt : Thank you for your comment. Of course, you are right. However, I am as happy with the Besier version, if not more -- because Besier curves seem more elegant to me than circular arcs.