# How can i draw ellipse in 3D?

Tags: graphics3d, version-9

I’m using mathematica 9.0 and want to draw an 
Ellipse in 3D. I notice that there is “Sphere”, but not ellipse... what is the easy way do draw one?

Thanks

Comment: Look for Ellipsoid in the documentation...

Comment: as in Graphics3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 3, 2}]]? or Graphics3D[
 Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   Ellipsoid[RandomReal[50, {3}], RandomReal[{1, 5}, 3]]}, {100}]]

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @rhermans He wrote *ellipse*, not *ellipsoid*. I do not think we should try to second guess what people mean.  It is entirely reasonable to want to draw an ellipse in 3D (after all it's a conic section, it's often drawn in 3D to illustrate that).  (Also, the edit made my answer look pretty stupid and prompted people to point that out.)

Comment: Another way: `Graphics3D[{Scale[Sphere[], {3, 1, 10}]}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs You are correct, I did a very bad edit. I have reverted it now. Apologies for my mistake, I will be more careful in the future, and try to not do more than three things at the same time.

Comment: @rhermans I did wonder if OP meant ellipse or ellipsoid because he mentions `Sphere`.  It is entirely possible that he meant ellipsoid ... but he wrote ellipse (twice). He should clarify.

Answer (score 7):

When I wrote this answer [the question clearly asked for an **ellipse**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/177045/1).

---

Look up [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) and use the equation of an ellipse.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 Cos[u], Sin[u], 0}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ellipse =!= Ellipsoid...

Comment: @Jens Of course it's not the same. The original poster wrote *ellipse* (not once but twice).  Then someone else edited the post and changed it to *ellipsoid* (only *after* I wrote the answer).  The original poster also mentioned `Sphere[]`, so he *might* have meant ellipsoid, but I am not going to play that kind of guessing game. If he asked for an ellipse, he will get an ellipse from me.

Comment: Sorry - didn't know this, but have been annoyed by the same issue several times before. In this case it would be a dupe of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6526/245.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{3 Cos[u] Cos[v], 2 Cos[u] Sin[v], 1 Sin[u]}  (*-(\[Pi]/2)<u<\[Pi]/2,0<v<2\[Pi] *), {u, -Pi/2,Pi/2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

plots an ellipsoid!